# Green dao relations

Tags: android, greendao

I have problem with green dao relations.

I have got two points.

First poin has second point.

I save this as here:

```
Visited_point visited_point = new Visited_point();
        visited_point.setPoint(point);
        visited_point.setUserId(1l);
        visited_point.setVisted_date(new Date());

        getDaoVisitedPoint().insert(visited_point);
```

and read as:

```
Visited_point visited_point = getDaoVisitedPoint().queryBuilder().where(Visited_pointDao.Properties.PointId.eq(point.getId())).unique();
```

When app is runing it work great, but when I restart app, visited point is always null.

Any sugestions?

From creator:

```
 Entity visited_points = schema.addEntity("Visited_point");
        visited_points.addIdProperty();
        Property userId = visited_points.addLongProperty("userId").notNull().getProperty();
        Property basePointId = visited_points.addLongProperty("pointId").notNull().getProperty();
        visited_points.addDateProperty("visted_date");
        visited_points.addToOne(points, basePointId);

Entity points = schema.addEntity("Point");
        points.addIdProperty().index();
        points.addFloatProperty("latitude");
        points.addFloatProperty("longitude");
        points.addIntProperty("ord");
        points.addBooleanProperty("special");
```

Comment: Show us the code of insert, setpoint, setuserid, setvisited_Date. Besides, show us your model visited_point

Comment: It also would help if you show us how you open the DB